# phpmyadmin privileges to change users

Tags: permissions, phpmyadmin

I recently logged into myphpadmin through the xampp control panel so that I could add a new user to a database.  I logged in as root as I always have but now I get a warning that says "You do not have the privileges to administrate the users!"  My config.inc.php has the 'auth_type' set to config.  I tried setting it to "cookie" and "http" as I found as suggestions on here but it doesn't seem to change anything.  I need to be able to add users and change permissions.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was eventually able to work this out by logging into phpMyAdmin and then typing the following into the SQL cmd window:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Hopefully this will help someone else having this problem as well.